# C#: Apply method to array of strings after recognition of one particular string

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array of strings called "words". My array consists of a bunch of strings in patterns, where the first string of the pattern is "\"Parameters Table\"". I need to write a code to search words for "\"Parameters Table\"" and then perform a method on it (data.SortDataMethod()) only up until it recognizes "\"Parameters Table\"" again (where the patterns repeats), in which case it will repeat the same method until the next "\"Parameters Table\"" and so on until end of the file is reached. I'm not sure which loop to use or how to start reading an array from a certain point/index. Help. Please and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking for?

```
bool found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    if (words[i] == "\"Parameters Table\"")
    {
        found = !found;
    }
    if(found)
    {
        myMethod(words[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Great, so he will be running his method on each separate word, but only ones that are after an even amount of "Parameters Table" words. Not great. He wants chunks of words.

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
const string separator = "\"Parameteres Table\"";

// Get to the first separator
var cuttedWords = words.SkipWhile(x => x != separator).Skip(1);

// Run as long as there is anything left to scan
while (cuttedWords.Any())
{
    // Take data from the last found separator until the next one, exclusively
    var data = cuttedWords.TakeWhile(x => x != separator).ToArray();

    // Step through cuttedWords to update where the last found separator was
    cuttedWords = cuttedWords.Skip(data.Length + 1);

    // Do what you want with the sub-array containing information
    performWork(data);
}
```

**Example:**

```
var words = new[] {"0", "1", "~", "2", "3", "~", "4", "5", "~", "6", "7", "~", "8"};

var cuttedWords = words.SkipWhile(x => x != "~").Skip(1);

while (cuttedWords.Any())
{
    var data = cuttedWords.TakeWhile(x => x != "~").ToArray();
    cuttedWords = cuttedWords.Skip(data.Length + 1);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", data));
}
```

**Output:**

```
2,3
4,5
6,7
8
```

Comment: Your approach does not work if his intention is to sort the array in place.

Comment: @Sven Your argument is invalid, since his sorting had nothing to do with his question. He wanted to cut the array into logical parts so he could then work on those parts separately - the fact that he then sorts them is irrelevant, and I don't see why he would care about in-place anyways. Not much memory issues these days.